# javascript keyboard shortcuts/hotkeys in background

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to access keyboard shortcuts even when my tab is not selected - for example, to be able to have "push-to-talk" functionality. I suppose this would ask for permission first, like the fullscreen APIs? I essentially just want to request that a function be called for a key combination, like this:

```
if (requestKeyboardShortcut("Ctrl+C", function() {
      //key pressed
    }, function () {
      //key released
    })) {
  //request succeeded
}
```

Is this possible? Is it even being considered? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add cross-page functionality, you'd need to rely on a browser plugin such as Java, AIR, or Silverlight, and even then I'm pretty certain this functionality wouldn't be supported. Whichever you choose, would require elevated privileges to be able to capture the events.

I know that certain browsers have opened their APIs for JavaScript to make certain types of requests for elevated privileges, however the main reason that cross-page event capturing would be to prevent the possibility of cross-page key-logging.

Imagine you use a site that captures key events across pages, and then you open a tab and log into Gmail or your bank account. Even if you approved of a website, it could be compromised in the future.

Comment: Well, if you saw my example, it was only requesting access for a certain key combination, not every key press, which wouldn't really compromise anything. (You wouldn't know every key pressed in another page, only that a certain key combination was pressed.)

Comment: @CodeRarity, but that's simply not how JavaScript binds key events, and could possibly still pose a security threat.

Answer (score 0):

Caveat emptor, I am not an expert so take the following with a grain of salt.

I do not believe browsers will let you do that across tabs like you desire.

What you *might* do is create a browser-specific plugin that tries to catch all Ctrl+C events and then open the tab in question. In case you need to target more browser, you might want to look at a cross-browser plugin abstraction layer like [BabelExt](http://babelext.com/2012/03/23/babelext-is-ready-in-beta-form/)

Good luck finding a final solution :)

Comment: But would that still work when the browser is minimized? Going with the push to talk example, you could be playing a game in another window. The way it looks, this may be the only option however.

Comment: @CodeRarity No, I don't believe so. Opera might actually have the functionality with their widget engine.